# Accessing file properties in nw.js

Tags: javascript, html, nw.js

I am create a native application using nw.js. Here, is my code snippet:

```
<input id="fileDialog" type="file" accept=".pdf,.epub" multiple/><a id="add" href="#">Add</a>
```

Here is my js code:

```
document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function(){
          document.getElementById("fileDialog").click();
});
document.querySelector('#fileDialog')
    .addEventListener("change", function() {
    var filePath = this.value;
        alert(filePath);
});
```

I am able to get file path of the selected files. Is it possible to access   the files' properties?

Answer (score 0):

### File statistics

You can get some statistics on your file using [fs.stat](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback) function that generates [fs.Stats](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats) object. It has modification and creation time, size of file, permission modes, etc.

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.stat('path/to/file', function(err, stats) {
    console.log(stats);
});
```

---

### Retrieving metadata

If you mean properties as metadata (title, publisher, ISBN, language, etc.), there are different metadata formats. In your specific case: XMP for PDF and DCMES for EPUB.

1. To read metadata from **PDF** file try this module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfmeta

   ```
   const pdfMeta = require('pdfmeta');

   pdfMeta.getInfo('path/to/file').then(function(data) {
       console.log(data);
   });
   ```
2. To read metadata from **EPUB** file try this module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/epub-metadata

   ```
   const epubMetadata = require('epub-metadata');

   epubMetadata.getInfo('path/to/file').then(function(data) {
       console.log(data);
   });
   ```